# React: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I'm using React and Dj-Rest-Auth for my authentication. I was able to set up the login page, registration page and the email confirmation page. But when i try to set up the Password Reset page i get this error every time i submit an email address inside the reset password form:

```
django          | django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be fixed?

This is how i set it all up:

urls.py

```
# API URLS
urlpatterns += [
    # API base url
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
    # DRF auth token
    path("auth-token/", obtain_auth_token),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls'))
]
```

reset.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import axios from "axios"
import { API } from '../api'

export function Reset() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    
    function handleSubmit(values, { resetForm }) {
        setLoading(true)
        axios.post(API.auth.passwordReset, values)
            .then(res => {
                resetForm()
                setSuccess(true)
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {success && "You will receive a verification email."}
            {loading && "Loading..."}
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    email: '',
                }}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                {({ errors, touched }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <Field name="email">
                            {({ field, form }) => (
                                <label className="mt-3 block">
                                    <span className="text-gray-700">Email</span>
                                    <input
                                    {...field}
                                    type="text"
                                    className="
                                        mt-1
                                        block
                                        w-full
                                        rounded-md
                                        border-gray-300
                                        shadow-sm
                                        focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50
                                    "
                                    placeholder=""
                                    style={
                                        form.touched.email && form.errors.email ? (
                                            { border: '2px solid var(--primary-red)'}
                                        ) : null
                                    }
                                    />
                                </label>
                            )}
                        </Field>

                       
                        <button className="mt-3 bg-blue-100 rounded-md shadow-sm text-lg px-5 py-3 hover:bg-blue-200" 
                            type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </Form>
                )}

            </Formik>
        </div>
    )

}
```

App.js

```
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} exact />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} exact />
              <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset />} exact />
              <Route path="/accounts/password_reset_confirm" element={<ResetConfirm />} exact />
              <Route path="/accounts/confirm-email/:key" element={<ConfirmEmail />} exact />
```

Api.js

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
const apiURL = `${baseURL}/api`

export const API = {
    auth: {
        login: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/login/`,
        logout: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/logout/`,
        passwordReset: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/`,
        passwordResetConfirm: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/`,
        signup: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/registration/`,
        verifyEmail: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/registration/verify-email/`
    },
    facilities: {
        list: `${apiURL}/facilities/`,
        retrieve: id => `${apiURL}/facilities/${id}/`,
        update: id => `${apiURL}/facilities/${id}/update/`,
    }
}
```

Adapters.py

```
from typing import Any

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpRequest


class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request: HttpRequest):
        return getattr(settings, "ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)

    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            context["activate_url"] = (
                "http://localhost:3000/accounts/confirm-email/" + context["key"]
            )
        else:
            context["activate_url"] = (
                settings.FRONTEND_URL + "/accounts/confirm-email/" + context["key"]
            )
        return super().send_mail(template_prefix, email, context)


class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request: HttpRequest, sociallogin: Any):
        return getattr(settings, "ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please share the `api.js` file that you are using to import `API`?. It seems that the requests are being sent to wrong endpoints.

Comment: @mtzd I added the api.js above. Thank you for checking it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your `Api.js` file, it looks fine to me. I checked the `dj-rest-auth` docs and I found that your problem is included in the [FAQ](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/8a460ecf9a72aec269b75160e5c97f7ed608e247/docs/faq.rst) (see question 2). There they suggest we need to add a url pattern with the name `password_reset_confirm` so you should modify your `urls.py` file to something like:

```py
# API URLS
urlpatterns += [
   # sample url pattern from dj-rest-auth demo
   path("password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/",
       TemplateView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"),
       name='password_reset_confirm'),
   # API base url
   path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
   # DRF auth token
   path("auth-token/", obtain_auth_token),
   path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
   path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls'))
]
```

I used the same structure as they provide in the [`demo`](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/8a460ecf9a72aec269b75160e5c97f7ed608e247/demo/demo/urls.py) but using `path` instead of `url`. To see how the file `password_reset_confirm.html` file should look like you can check the same file in the demo (https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/8a460ecf9a72aec269b75160e5c97f7ed608e247/demo/templates/password_reset_confirm.html).

Also, you could include the default urls that the Django authentication system provides for that in `django.contrib.auth` (the `urls` can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/urls.py), you will notice there's a url pattern named `password_reset_confirm` in L26). So another way of solving the problem would be to include those `urls` in your `urls.py` file like (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views-1):

```py
# API URLS
urlpatterns += [
   # include urls from django.contrib.auth
   path('dj-auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
   # API base url
   path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
   # DRF auth token
   path("auth-token/", obtain_auth_token),
   path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
   path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls'))
]
```

Comment: `/app/seniorpark/users/adapters.py` is using the `context` dictionary in L15 and trying to access the "key" key. But the `context` dictionary that it's being handled doesn't have a "key" key, thats why you get a KeyError (see [this](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/)). Either the "key" key in `context` is not being saved in your views or you should consider using another key that is in your `context` dictionary (like `context["existing_key"]` if `context={'existing_key': '/key_value'}`. I don't know about the logic you're using but you should check what comes in `context` first.

Comment: After playing with this for a while i found out something strange: I can take out the key part and i will get to the password reset form after clicking on the link i get inside the command line. But it uses the wrong port. It uses the backend port even though the context clearly specifies port 3000. It seems like password reset and signup share the same "send_mail" function but only the signup will actually use port 3000 inside the email. I added the adapters.py at the top to clearify. So it will complain about the key but not use the rest of the function.

Comment: Don't know what could be happening here without the full context. I would suggest to inspect how the signup and password reset adapters are behaving.